# What is meant by /sbin/init too old?

Tags: linux, upstart, daemon

I am trying to use `Upstart` to daemonize a script. So, I made a `.conf` file under `/etc/init/`. Now to check the conf file I did

```
init-checkconf /etc/init/ping_me.conf
```

And it says

```
ERROR: version of /sbin/init too old
```

My linux kernel version is `3.19.0-20-generic`.

The Upstart is unable to configure the service. Hence `service ping_me start` is not working. So, if `init` can be updated, how can I update it?

Comment: You'll need to add ping_me.conf

Comment: And the version of Ubuntu which you're using.

Comment: I'm using 15.04.

Comment: I'll need to add the file where? I've already created it in /etc/init/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, on Ubuntu 15.04, `/sbin/init` is **NOT** *Upstart*.

*Upstart* is at `/sbin/upstart`.

By default, 15.04 is using *Systemd* instead of *Upstart *.

You should look into creating a *Systemd* unit file instead.

See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers